# Can't update pear packages (redirected but no location)

Tags: php, pear

I have Pear installed in my Ubuntu local machine, and I have been using this environment without problems for near a year. I updated pear packages several times without issues. But I can't do it june-july more or less. It says "Error getting channel info .. xml not valid (redirected but no location)). Can anyone help me? I didn't change anything in Pear directly (as I can remember) and suddently I can't upgrade any package.

This is my pear version (pear -V):

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3
Zend Engine Version: 2.4.0
Running on: Linux oficina11 3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 20:52:24 UTC 2013 x86_64
```

My configuration (pear config-show):

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/share/php/doc
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/share/php
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/share/php/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/share/php/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /build/buildd/php5-5.4.9/pear-build-download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/share/php/test
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/share/php/htdocs
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            2
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /etc/pear/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /root/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear/pear.conf
```

The messages it returns when I try to upgrade (pear upgrade-all):

```
Error getting channel info from components.ez.no: File http://components.ez.no:80/p/packages.xml not valid (redirected but no location)
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: File http://pear.php.net:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (redirected but no location)Error getting channel info from pear.phpunit.de: File http://pear.phpunit.de:80/rest/p/packages.xml not valid (redirected but no location)
... (all the rest of packages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has a similar problem, it is solved now, it's the firewall. For any reason, I can download files from the browser, and I can install or update packages by APT, but firewall is blocking PEAR downloads. I have added PEAR URL's to secured sites and now it's working.